# Powershell: Stopping a process

Tags: powershell

I am just learning Powershell, and doing practicing I have noticed something interesting.
I pick a process, and I stop it the good old ways `("Stop-Process -Name" or "Stop-Process -ID")` and the process sends me a popup window, that it will quit. I press OK button and it quits.
Now, when I close this process via Task Manager (right click -> end process, usual way), I never get this popup message. So I assume, Task Manager does something different.
Question: How can I stop this (or any) process the Task Manager way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `-Force`

```
Stop-Process -Name Test -Force
```

Also make sure you are NOT using `-Confirm`